# Switch working copy directory without updating

Tags: svn, switch-statement, working-copy

**Scenario:** Repository structure changed from */trunk/* to */projectName/trunk/* and the local copy is outdated and has a lot of modifications.

**Question:** How can I update the working copy directory path without updating the files.

Normally the solution to directory changes within the same repository would be to use the *svn switch* command. The problem is that it performs an update upon execution, the working copy is outdated and has a lot of local modifications that would conflict with the current revision.

What I'm looking for is the same behavior of the *--relocate* switch, which updates the path but doesn't update the files. This way I can regain the ability check the statuses and differences for each file separately while maintaining the local copy functional (this is my main concern).

The *switch --help* provides a few arguments to deal with conflicts but I could find nothing that would stop the update altogether.

Any ideas? Thanks a lot.

Comment: You will have to deal with the conflicts at some time. And the more you wait, the more you'll have conflicts and the more difficult it will be to solve them. I would switch ASAP.

Comment: I agree, the problem with this particular scenario is that we use the files on the repository as a model application that is replicated with local changes in various locations. The structure change in the repository affects all the locations hence the need to minimize the conflicts.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The solution for this particular case was simpler than I thought.

*`svn switch`* performs an update to the latest revision in the repository by default, specifying the BASE revision (last revision obtained from the repository) of the working copy left most of the files untouched.

I got the BASE revision of my working copy (294) by issuing the *`svn info`* command.

Then just issuing the switch command with the BASE revision updated the repository path leaving most of the files untouched.

*`svn switch -r 294 /projectName/trunk/`*

Comment: This approach did not leave my files untouched. It actually switched to that location and updated my workspace with whatever that specific revision and location has